# How can I exclude properties when serializing an object to JSON with jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class implementing `Serializable`, which is mapped to a database table. It looks like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    public String email;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    public String status;
}
```

For the most part, I want all these properties to be included in the JSON. However, there is a specific case where I want to exclude `status`, but I can't figure out a good way of doing this with Jackson.

My controller looks something like this:

```java
public class UserController {
    
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Inject
    public UserController(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public CompletionStage<JsonNode> getUserList() {
        // Get list of Users and return the JSON; with all User properties included
    }

    public CompletionStage<JsonNode> getUser(Long userId) {
        
        // Get a single user from JPA, in a promise
        return userDatabase.get(userId).thenApply(user -> { // user is type User
 
            // Here, I don't want to include "status" in the JSON.
            return mapper.valueToTree(user);
        });
    }
}
```

So when I do `mapper.valueToTree(user)`, of course, it includes all properties of `User`, but I want to exclude `status` in this specific route/function while keeping it included in all other places its serialized.

I know I can use `@JsonIgnore` to ignore it always, but can I do this just *sometimes*?

Some solutions I thought of are:

- `filter` through the properties and get rid of `status`
- Copy `user` over to an `ObjectNode` and manually remove `status`

Neither of these seems ideal though, I feel like there has to be a cleaner approach with Jackson.

Comment: what specifically are the "other" cases you speak of? are you saying that you only want to exclude the `status` field when serializing an object into a `JsonNode` specifically?

Comment: @ChrisGong Sorry, I meant that in one route, I dont want to include `status`, but in all other routes, I do want to include `status`. In all cases, it is being serialized to json.

Comment: I may be getting ahead of myself but I believe the two solutions that you deem as not ideal are the only two ways outside of annotations to achieve your desired outcome. But someone can feel free to put in some more input.